# Unable to create usr in Keycloak via Python

Tags: ssl, python-requests, keycloak, python-3.8

I am attempting to create a simple class to wrap the Keycloak REST API (to say create a user), and it works fine when using `curl` but does not work when using the Python Requests library. It gets the token just fine, but I get a 400 "unknown_error" when attempting to hit the createUser endpoint. My initial thought was it had something to do with me turning off SSL verification in requests.post, but I am not sure. Thanks!

Here is the shell script that succeeds:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOKEN=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://www.<KEYCLOAK_SERVER>.com/auth/realms/kaizo/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
    --data-urlencode 'client_secret=<SECRET>')

ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $TOKEN | jq -j '.access_token')

RESPONSE=$(curl --location --request POST 'https://www.titancloak.com/auth/admin/realms/kaizo/users' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer '${ACCESS_TOKEN} \
    --data-raw '{"firstName":"Bloodhound", "lastName":"Gang", "email":"u2jds7d@ase.edu", "username":"tra.la.la"}')

echo $RESPONSE
```

And here is the Python code that does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests

BASE_URL = "https://www.<KEYCLOAK_SERVER>.com"
def get_token():
    url = BASE_URL + "/auth/realms/kaizo/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    data = {
       "grant_type": "client_credentials",
       "client_id": "admin-cli",
       "client_secret": "<SECRET>"
    }
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data,
        verify=False
    ).json()
    return response.get('access_token')

def create_user(token: str):
    url = BASE_URL + "/auth/admin/realms/kaizo/users"
    data = {
        "firstName":"jon",
        "lastName":"Snow",
        "email":"mkm29@case.edu",
        "username":"jon.snow"
    }
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data=data,
        verify=False,
        headers=headers
    ) # cert=("/Users/mitchellmurphy/Developer/ans/flaskql/app/authentication/titancloak.crt")
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = get_token()
    print(token[:25])
    user = create_user(token)
    print('Response[%s]: %s ' % (user.status_code, user.json()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the format of the data sent to Keyloak as so: `data=json.dumps(data)`